# How to do game dev without downloading binaries?

Tags: teaching

I am trying to start a student club for game development. My initial plan was to have students start by modifying an existing Open Source game, such as Sauerbraten, Tux Racer, or SuperTux. The students all have Windows computers, the problem is they're locked from installing any binaries such as these games, which would be needed to get started. So is there some option for creating a collaborative project that wouldn't require downloading of binaries to do?

Comment: Is it specifically installers/elevated permissions that are blocked, or are students blocked from running any non-whitelisted executable, even in user mode? There are for example game engines that will produce executable games that do not need an installer (provided you can arrange for educational copies of the engine software to be installed on the PCs in advance), if working with a game engine would meet your goals. But if the school's security software blocks any unrecognized executable (even one built locally), then your options may be more limited.

Comment: Are there any development tools installed? Does the security configuration allow running binaries from USB?

Comment: For many open source projects, you do not need to download a playable binary of the game; you can clone the repository and then build it to produce an executable locally. However, your students will need the appropriate build tools installed. If you can't install build tools and the student computers don't have any, it's very unlikely you'll be able to get anywhere.

Comment: To clarify, though I think its possible they can run a binary, I think the school district policy prohibits this, so I think i'm stuck with either some dev tools built into Windows that maybe hidden (perhaps Python is installed under windows like it is in Mac?) ...or some online solution. My intent with using Saurerbrauten, is, if installed on the machine, they can edit levels (it has a level editor), but also can edit textures, add in their own models, and make a very custom game without compiling or coding.

Comment: I don't think Windows ships with any build tools, and even if it does they will almost certainly be disabled by the security policy.

Comment: @Kevin The school may have dev tools installed for course work.

Comment: @Village It sounds like the first step is to discuss the matter with the school. Once you have a clear understanding of what is & is not allowed, you'll be address the issues being raised in the comments & hopefully get answers that will work with your situation.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're working under a very restrictive environment.

If you really can't run any non-whitelisted executables at all, then your safest bet might be to teach HTML5 game development.

You can author these games with as little as a text editor (though if you can work with the school's IT folks to pre-install an IDE on the machines, that's a much better experience for the students and offers more power in what they can do).

And you can run and debug these games in a standard web browser, with no new executables to download or run.

Modern JavaScript is much more powerful and better-performing than it used to be, and you can even teach conventional game 3D rendering and shaders via WebGL if you're so inclined. (This will likely require an IDE though, due to some complications in loading textures for use in WebGL - you need a web server running locally to appease browsers' security restrictions)